# AppEngine constantly writing to appengine-web.xml causes Eclipse build loop. How do I stop it?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jetty

I'm working with a Google AppEngine project using Jetty as local server for my project. This has worked fine up until now, where I suddenly observe that Eclipse sticks in a automatic build loop whenever the server is running. Using SysInternals Process Monitor, I've detected that the reason probably is that some code in the AppEngine SDK (through the Jetty process) is writing to one of my project files - `war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` every couple of seconds.

This happens before I've done any queries to my service of any kind.

Anyone have any ideas as to why? How can I stop it writing to this file? Or is it possible to make Eclipse *not* build when this particular file is written to?

**edit:** It's not Jetty, but probably something in the AppEngine SDK, but I still seek an answer.

Comment: There is no code in Jetty that will modify any file called `appengine-web.xml`.  Something else is modifying that file, not Jetty.

Comment: Ok, it's probably some code in the AppEngine framework. Edited the question and title